# Collect user form input data from a web site

Tags: marketing-cloud, data, form, web

My client would like to collect data from persons browsing the website, i.e. fname, lname and email and store it in a Marketing Cloud DE without synchronizing to Sales Cloud.

Would Web-Collect satisfy this need? Would I be able to take the form and then imbed it in an iFrame on the website?

Thx,

RP

Answer (score 4):

As per your situation, I'd recommend using DE manager since it is really easy to implement.

You'll need couple of things:

1) Setup the Data Extension in Salesforce Marketing Cloud with field that would match with your form page/iframe.

2) Details of your SFMC account and DE:

- **_clientID** - your account number
- **_deExternalKey** - the external key for the data extension to receive the subscriber information
- **_successURL and _errorURL** - the pages shown to the subscriber after they complete the form

3) Sample Code:

```
<form action="http://cl.s#.exct.net/DEManager.aspx" name="subscribeForm" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_clientID" value="12345" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_deExternalKey" value="WebCollectSubs" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_action" value="add" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_returnXML" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_successURL" value="http://example.com/Success" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_errorURL" value="http://example.com/Failed" /> Email:
    <input type="text" name="Email">
    <br /> First Name:
    <input type="text" name="FirstName">
    <br /> Last Name:
    <input type="text" name="LastName">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

4) When referencing WebCollect URLs on a secure page change the web collect URL to https. Also use the Name field value of those fields as defined in the data extension for the web form.

5) Also determine what instance are you on - cl.s#.exct.net? For example: s1, s4, s7, etc.

6) Reference: **[Web Collect](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/web_collect/)**

Comment: Clarification, the persons who will be providing their fname, lname and email are not known (do not have a subscriber ID) to us. What impact does that have on the solution you are proposing? Excuse the neophyte question but isn't there some way to quickly create a form in MC and then publish it to simply gather data from visitors to a publicly accessible web site?

Comment: @RichardPage The subsciber ID is a unique identifier for a contact in sfmc, if you're sending emails or sms that's where the subsciberID or subscriber key needs to be set. In this situation you'd not need to setup subscriber key if you're not setting DE as a sendable DE - the form should just log the data without being a sendable DE.